# use of do_action() without any functions attached

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

According to docs:

> do_action( string $tag,  $arg = '' )
>
> Execute functions hooked on a specific action hook.

I have already written plugins. and they have many `do_action()` function without any functions hooked to that specific hook.

What is the use of  `do_action( 'wpdocs_i_am_hook');` with `wpdocs_i_am_hook` used nowhere else?

Comment: this cas be used by other plugins to do custom actions.

Answer (score 4):

If you are seeing this in plugins (or leaving them in your own) then you are making your plugins more developer friendly.

For example, we can use `do_action('stv_plugin_on_form_submit', $entry, $form, $user);` inside a custom plugin that tracks form submissions. After all of your code and before the function completes, adding the `do_action` would enable another developer to extend the functionality of your plugin.

Here's my "extension" to your plugin via the action defined:

```
add_action('stv_plugin_on_form_submit', 'tom_custom_stv_plugin_on_form_submit');
function tom_custom_stv_plugin_on_form_submit($entry, $form, $user){
    //send HTTP POST to API
}
```

If you're using this technique, you are ensuring that your plugin (or theme) is more flexible for other to use in the future.

Further reading:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/
- https://wpshout.com/apply_filters-do_action/
- https://zellwk.com/blog/wordpress-actions-and-filters/

Comment: I think an important addendum to this is that basically means that your plugin now has its own API and code is going to depend on these filters and actions having a decent level of stability.